# Java exception fail fast approach

Tags: java, android

I have been coding mostly in C++ this last year. I have become quite fond of asserts when developing my code. I like to employ the fail fast mentality of software development.

In Java I thought I could implement this using Exceptions. But I am confused why java forces you to handle exceptions.

What if a condition is not met, and I want the app to immediately crash, and print out an error message to log?

Is there a way I can do this? I find exceptions and try/catch to be syntactically gross, since I am used to asserts.

How can I implement a fail fast approach to software design in Java?

ps. I develop on Android, but I feel like this question is a more general Java question.

Comment: why not call `System.exit`

Comment: 'Gross' is rich. You prefer aborts and core dumps to program-defined handling?

Answer (score 3):

The `assert` statement exists in Java as well, if that's what you're looking for. It actually has *more* functionality than the corresponding statement in C++, because it allows an assertion message. In C++, `static_assert` allows an assertion message, but the normal non-static `assert` doesn't.